# Can someone give me a better understanding of this error? Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I recently updated my version of android studio, when i create an activity now i get this error. Can someone explain this error to me?

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\eche\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027srcCompat\u0027 in package \u0027com.drawscape.drawscape\u0027","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\eche\Documents\Drawscape 2.05\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_adminoptions.xml","position":{"startLine":24}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
C:\Users\eche\Documents\Drawscape 2.05\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_adminoptions.xml:25: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.drawscape.drawscape'

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.875 secs

Comment: Please post the complete gradle log.